# Flash .app/.exe buttons stop working on fullscreen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a web project that I've been asked to make into a DVD. All seems to work well except for the fullscreen.

When I hit my "fullscreen" button in my .app (or even go fullscreen from the menu), all of my buttons stop working (including the ability to go back to my normal-sized screen).

Is there a way to get around this??

Comment: Buttons?  As in keyboard keys?

Comment: Buttons, as in movieclips with the buttonMode = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working through a series of steps:

1. Made sure I had the latest version of the Flash Player/Projector.
2. Opened the .swf file in the Flash player.
3. Published as a projector file with a DIFFERENT NAME as my .swf file.

Now it works.